# IOS 6.x How to use Sprite Sheet with initWithContentsOfFile, imageNamed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have been searching these threads and other sites but have not come across a way to do this both efficiently and memory friendly. And so, here is my story:

My IOS (iPad) app uses sprite sheets (a large image, such as 2k x 2k at 16 bpp, which is composed of many smaller sprites). I have created a sprite atlas class which manages these sheets, handle sprite animations, and other features.

The idea (in the load method) is to load in the sheet from the file system, split it apart into UIImages (one per sprite) using CGImageCreateWithImageInRect, and then dispose of the loaded sheet. Seems simple enough.

Note that the sheet is loaded into a UIImage by initWithContentsOfFile or imageNamed (more on that below).

The desire is to save file memory by using sprite sheets, and then save runtime memory by only retaining the actual sprites themselves as UIImages. In my experiments thus far this is what I find happening:

If I use initWithContentsOfFile I see (from Instruments) that it appears to do a file open, fstat64, and close for the file for EACH sprite in it. This takes an horrendous amount of time to load all the sprites. It actually seems to load the entire sheet, grab one sprite, close the sheet, then load the entire sheet again for the next sprite, until they are all created. Also it appears to consume lots of memory (proven by the "received memory warning" after just the second sheet loaded, as well as by Instruments allocations).

Next I tried imageNamed (which caches the sheet). The file loading occurs once and so it is MUCH faster. All seems good and in fact and I can go until many sheets are loaded. But eventually the dreaded "received memory warning" appears... and a few seconds later the app crashes. It appears to be the case that the cached image (even though the pointer is set to null after pulling out the sprites) never goes away. I have read several posts that also state this seems to be its behavior (although other posts say other things, so that is not conclusive - does anyone know definitively?).

And so it appears that neither method is what is needed. What I want is to load the file, pull out each sprite into its own UIImage, then have the UIImage for the big sheet file released completely.

I have read one site that talked about using the initWithContentsOfFile approach to set up their own caching system (rather than trust the IOS plan with imageNamed) so they can release the image when desired. However, I don't think they had sprite sheets in mind.

And so, I turn this over to the experts out there to see if there are some ideas on how to get both fast load times AND use minimal memory.

[and yes, I know that IOS 7 has SpriteKit. But this needs to also work on IOS 6.x.]

One interesting data point is that on an original iPad the imageNamed version actually works fine with no "received memory warning". It might have been IOS 5.x. But the app will crash on the iPad 2 device.

I am not including code here because what I am after is an understanding of the mechanics involved with how memory is used with these functions related to image handling.

And while I am at it, can someone please clarify this point:

True or False:  When using CGImageCreateWithImageInRect, what it does is actually creates from new memory a bitmap the size of the rectangle specified and then COPIES from the original UIImage the pixels into this new memory (as opposed to setting up the bitmap format and having a pointer point into the original UIImage's pixel data). I think this is True, but want verification.

Thanks!

Comment: Update: Via instruments and the menu item to force a memory warning in the simulator, I was able to verify that indeed cached images (using imageNamed) are released. So, that is good. For the other case of initContentsWithFile, I have tried numerous ideas, including copying the entire sheet into another UIImage and releasing the original and pulling the sprites out of that copy. Still, the file I/O happens for every sprite! It is almost like the sprite sheet is not actually loaded until rendered (very lazy). Would sure like to know more about what happens behind the scenes there.

Comment: @user232658 I have the similar problem. Do you have fix it?